# Is there a way in Azure Search to control relevancy boosting in suggestions API?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Is there a way to control relevancy when using suggestions api? I am aware of search api allowing to specify scoring profiles but there don't seem to be a way to specify them in suggestions api. Basically I need fuzzy searching (currently supported in suggestions api only) but I need to be able to control which results come on top, boosting matches in specific fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Search just added support for Lucene query syntax in search queries. You can now issue fuzzy search using the query language. This feature is available as a preview in the api-version 2015-02-28-Preview.

Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt589323.aspx for more details.

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

Nate

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we don't currently provide a way to control relevancy in Suggest Api. However, we will be rolling out a feature that supports the Lucene query language in the Search api very soon. Fuzzy match, scoped search, and term weighting are some of the features that the query language supports. I will reply to this message when the feature is ready (in a week or so).